# Adding a join in a Views field handler class constructor?

Tags: 7, views

In a Views field handler, one can define additional fields to accompany the base field defined in hook_field_data. These field values are based on database columns on the same row, and they can be used in the render function. Somewhat like this:

```
my_views_field_handler extends views_handler_field {

  function construct() {
    parent::construct();
    $this->additional_fields['property2'] = 'property2';
  }

  function render($values) {
    return $this->get_value($values) . $this->get_value($values, 'property2');
  }

}
```

But is it also possible to define a join in the constructor? One of my database columns is an id of another entity. I have been using it somewhat like this, but this generates quite a lot of overhead (loading an entire entity for each row).

```
  function render($values) {
    $id = $this->get_value($values, 'property2');
    $entity = entity_load_single('my_type', $id);

    if ($entity->some_other_field == TRUE) {
      return $this->get_value($values);
    }
    else {
      return 'none';
    }
  }
```

So is there something like a join I can use in the constuctor, so I can query the other entity table directly instead of having to load the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to have already defined that relationship in the view. Per the docs for [`views_handler_field::add_additional_fields($fields)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_field.inc/function/views_handler_field%3A%3Aadd_additional_fields/7.x-3.x):

> @param $fields
>   An array of fields. The key is an identifier
>   used to later find the field alias used. The value is either a
>   string in which case it's assumed to be a field on this handler's
>   table; or it's an array in the form of
>   @code **array('table'
>   => $tablename, 'field' => $fieldname)** @endcode

Thus, say you had a field handler for a field on the `node` table with a defined *author relationship* to the `users` table. You could do this:

```
  function construct() {
    parent::construct();
    $this->additional_fields['mail'] = array(
      'table' => 'users',
      'field' => 'mail',
    );
  }
```

Which would allow you to do this:

```
function render($values) {
  //Get the mail column from the users table.
  $this->get_value($values, 'mail');
}
```

For your case, you'll need to define the entity relationship to your base table before you can do this.

Comment: Yes, I do remember reading something like this in the past. I'll try it later today :)

Comment: This did it, bounty unlocks in a few more hours.